# The ads1115 buffer overflow with low sample rates

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, buffer, i2c, adc

I'm doing a acquisition system for analog sensors (water pressures and water turbidity) using a raspberry pi 3B and a ADC (ADS1115).

The problem that i am facing is that from time to time the buffer (or whatever) gets full and the ads1115 gives a **zero** reading.

The lower the data rate (or whatever), the more frequent are the nulls.

Here I show the plots that i have:

DATA RATE = 8 sps

[8sps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSNjY.png)

DATA RATE = 16 sps

[16sps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7wwx.png)

The drops were turbidity goes to zero and pressure to negative values are a consequence of the zero readings in the ADC.

Is there a way to clear the buffer (or whatever) of the ADC? Or do you think the problem is other?

The connections that i have are all in the GitHub repository: https://github.com/Ricardosgeral/relier/blob/master/README.md

The code for the reading of the ADS1115 is in this file https://github.com/Ricardosgeral/relier/blob/master/analogsensor_thread.py

I would appreciate some directions here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am developing some embedded devices ads1115 and raspbery pi on windows 10 iot core,
this is my steps, i wish helpfull for you.

```
private I2cDevice _converter1;
```

here is my setup bits for ads1115

```
var i2CSettings1 = new I2cConnectionSettings(0x48)
                {
                    BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode,
                    SharingMode = I2cSharingMode.Shared
                };

                var i2C1 = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");
                var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(i2C1);
                var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

                _converter1 = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id, i2CSettings1);
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x01, 0xc4, 0x60 });
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 }); //rate
                _converter1.Write(new byte[] { 0x03, 0xff, 0xff });
```

after setup maybe i can use alert pin of ads1115, i connect alert pin to pi digital pin and triger my reading code, sometimes i am reading in a loop, for loop you must wait for 20 miliseconds
here is my reading code

```
_converter1.WriteRead(new byte[] { 0x0 }, bytearray1);
                            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                                Array.Reverse(bytearray1);
                            var value1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytearray1, 0);
```

referance voltage is very very important, i use raspbery pi 3.3 vcc for referance voltage and other important thing is raspbery have 2 input voltage line
one of usb
and other is 5 volt vcc pin.

usb port line is regulated but
5 volt vcc pin is NOT REGULATED

if you use 5 volt vcc pin for raspbery ads1115 not read clearly,

with this code i can read every situation